# Encode and decode list of strings or integers in python

Tags: python

I am trying to set up cursor pagination in a flask API powered by elasticsearch. What I need to do is:

1. Take a list of numbers or strings, such as: `[33430999, 23.2]` and convert it into a string of characters that can be passed into a URL parameter, like `ckufencidf77`
2. Decode the string back into a list so that I can get the next set of data from elasticsearch: `ckufencidf77 -> [33430999, 23.2]`

Anybody know of a python package that does something like this?

Comment: According to which rule is `[33430999, 23.2]` related to `ckufencidf77`?

Comment: If you don't mind the length then I think you could simply convert entire list into url-safe-escaped string and feed it to `ast.literal_eval` later on.

Comment: first we would have to know what encoding it uses. Maybe it is standard `base64` ? Or maybe page use own encrypting to stop bots/scripts/spamers/hackers

Comment: @jupiterbjy I'd prefer using json for the data in flight so you can parse the value in multiple different languages. `ast.literal_eval` will quickly bound you to only Python. Having the RPC be language agnostic has a lot of advantages.

Comment: @flakes now to think of that, json sounds just right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use base64 and json.

To encode, first dump the data to a json string, and then base64 encode that string.

For decoding, do the reverse. Decode the base64 value to a string, and then load the json string as an object:

```
import base64, json


def encode(obj):
    return base64.b64encode(json.dumps(obj).encode()).decode()


def decode(data):
    return json.loads(base64.b64decode(data.encode()).decode())
```

```
>>> encode([33430999, 23.2])
WzMzNDMwOTk5LCAyMy4yXQ==
>>> decode(encode([33430999, 23.2]))
[33430999, 23.2]
```